# What is the R.id.realtabcontent in FragmentTabHost example?

Tags: android

Looking into documentation about [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup%28android.content.Context,%20android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,%20int%29) I see the `R.id.realtabcontent` in:

```
 mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

Just don't uderstand where did it come from and what shall I use. Thanks for a hint in advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318808/two-frame-layouts-in-fragmenttabs-example-of-android-support4demos for an explanation of the weird second container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setup (Context context, FragmentManager manager, int containerId)
```

Thats the container view. If you really don't understand it. Try to make a LinearLayout and put some indicator in it, then follow the example so you understand it better. In fact, another constor exist without the container :

```
public void setup (Context context, FragmentManager manager)
```

Comment: If I do so the layout goes beyond a screen and I don't see tabs, don't you know why?

Comment: the container doesn't have to be full screen , try making the container half the screen of your Activity and setup in there.